# Styling issues while rendering wordpress template in react

Tags: css, reactjs, wordpress

I have a react application which fetches the wordpress post content and renders it through WP REST API.
The designer templates that are created have lots of CSS classnames around it.
Now when I view this post content in react application, no styles are applied as the classnames are particular to wordpress theme/plugin.

**Question:** Is there a way to get all the related CSS, so that I can use it in react?

**Expected:** The template shown in react should be same as the post created in wordpress.

**Plugins used:** Elementor(to create shapes, style content etc..,)

**Tried Solutions:**

1. Keeping a copy of styles from WordPress in client application – not scalable as the CSS files in WP changes when Admin adds more themes/plugins.
2. Used AutoOptimize plugin to combine & minify all CSS files, and use the final generated file in react, but CSS concatenation has its own drawbacks
3. Rendering the WP post directly in client application using permalink – This contains navigation header and other information of the site which we don’t want to expose in the client application

Answer (score 0):

The solution that can be tried over here is to get all the stylesheet links from wordpress and add it react head tag. If there are any dependent js links they can also be added. so now when the template is rendered in react it will have all the styles shown.

The other way is similar to the above one but lot easier. Get the total wordpress-post document via rest-api and pass it to iframe in react. In this the page doesn't break in any case because the html document will have all the links that needs to be rendered.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/320065/get-the-list-of-enqueued-registered-scripts-for-a-specific-post  -> refer this to check on how to get the stylesheet links and also document based on the post id.

https://www.haselt.com/blog/wp-rest-api-modifying-the-json-response -> Refer this to check on how to modify the json response.